# libvirt и virtualbox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual

Подобная тема уже поднималась на стаке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778638/libvirt-and-virtualbox-getting-started но мне не совсем удалось до конца разобраться. Я пересобрал пакет libvirt0 версии 1.3.1 согласно инструкции из указанной ссылки, и при вызове `$ virsh -V` получаю:

> Утилита командной строки virsh для libvirt 1.3.1 Сайт:
>   http://libvirt.org/
>
> Собран с поддержкой:
>
> Гипервизоры: QEMU/KVM LXC UML Xen LibXL OpenVZ VMWare **VirtualBox** ESX Test
>
> Сеть: Remote Network Bridging Interface netcf Nwfilter VirtualPort
>
> Пространство данных: Dir Disk Filesystem SCSI Multipath iSCSI LVM RBD Sheepdog ZFS
>
> Другое: Daemon Nodedev
>
> AppArmor Secrets Debug Readline Modular

как я понимаю в пакет включилась поддержка VirtualBox.
При вызове `sudo virsh list --all`, я получаю пустой список(хотя домен запущен).
При команде `sudo virsh --connect vbox:///session` получаю ответ:

> error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
>
> error: internal error: unable to initialize VirtualBox driver API

запущенный вручную `libvirtd` выводит:

> error : dummyConnectOpen:90 : internal error: unable to initialize VirtualBox driver API
>
> error : virNetSocketReadWire:1626 : End of file while reading data: Input/output error

**UPD**: Проблема частично решена. а именно с `error: internal error: unable to initialize VirtualBox driver API`. версии до 1.3.5 могут работать максимум с 4-ым virtualbox'м... установка версии 2.0.0 решает эту проблему, но список виртуалок все так же пуст(

Comment: вы привели ссылку на древний вопрос, вызванный, судя по всему, древним багом. вы уверены, что пакет из вашей версии вашего дистрибутива **сейчас** собран без поддержки *virtualbox*? если затрудняетесь с ответом на мой вопрос, приведите, пожалуйста, название и версию вашего дистрибутива.

Comment: на момент написание вопроса была установлена версия пакета 1.3.1-10.0.1
Дистрибутив убунта 16.04  4.4.0-28-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 10:09:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: уточню: я говорил не о пересобранном вами пакете, а о том, который присутствует в репозитории *ubuntu*.

Comment: в репозитории крутится 1.3.1-10.1, недавно пересобрал версию 2.0.0, проблема частично решилась, описал в конце поста